# How to deal with Spanish including special characters in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I would like to import data into SQL Server using an Excel file in CSV format through SSIS. The data has been updated into the table however the values stored are not exactly as intended.

For example, `Disconfort Térmico` is stored as `Disconfort TÃ©r` in the table.

Could it be rectified by changing data type to `Nvarchar()`?

Comment: Given you know thats a possible solution, why not give it a try? And/or read the documentation?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the destination column type to NVARCHAR.

Comment: And if its a CSV file its not an Excel file - its a CSV file.

Comment: CSV files are *text* files, not Excel files. You can open and edit them with any text editor. `Ã©` is how a UTF8 text file would look if you opened it as if it used a single-byte codepage, which means your SSIS source is badly configured. Its codepage should be `65001`, the codepage for UTF8. It's the source that reads bytes from a file and forwards them as text to the rest of the dataflow.

Comment: Hey everyone I managed to solve it by changing the data type to Nvarchar() thanks!

Comment: Once this is fixed, change the table field to `nvarchar`. That's the Unicode text type in SQL Server. It just works, as your question proves - StackOverflow is a .NET application storing data in nvarchar fields in SQL Server. That's why you were able to write `Térmico` and I can write `Αυτό Εδώ` without problems

Comment: @clayton55 you also need to ensure you're reading the file correctly. `nvarchar` uses UTF16. What you posted are misinterpreted UTF8 bytes.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos fyi `nvarchar` uses UCS-2, unless the default database collation is one of the *_SC (Supplementary Character) collations at which point it then is using UTF-16. Applications can still store UTF-16 data regardless of the collation, but the SQL Server string functions will choke on anything outside of the Basic Multilingual Plane without the *_SC collation. Ref: [Supplementary Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Supplementary_Characters)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I know and I don't think anyone cares about those distinctions. Unless you try to store some of the newer flag emojis - stars and thumbsup/down work, which is enough for most business scenarios (ie feedback pages).

Comment: The supplementary planes contain way more than emoji (which, I agree, are a complete waste of time) - there are plenty of non-Euro languages in there, too.